# Why is failsafe: not executed with "mvn verify"?

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

Why is "failsafe:integration-test" not automatically executed with `mvn verify`?

According to `mvn help:describe ...` the `maven-failsafe-plugin` task "integraton-test" is supposed to be bound to the "integration-test" phase:

```
failsafe:integration-test
  Description: Run integration tests using Surefire.
  Implementation: org.apache.maven.plugin.failsafe.IntegrationTestMojo
  Language: java
  Bound to phase: integration-test
```

Yet `mvn verify` only executes "surefire:test" but not "failsafe:integration-test".

I do know how to fix that using `<executions>` as this is even in the "Usage" examples on the failsafe plugin homepage but I would like to understand why the two plugins behave differently.

There are file that match both `<include>` patterns:

```
src/test/java/de/lathspell/test/UselessThingTest.java
src/test/java/de/lathspell/test/UselessThingIT.java
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pom="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.lathspell</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The output:

```
[INFO] -------------------------< de.lathspell:test1 >-------------------------
[INFO] Building test1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /mnt/keller_christian/workspace/test1/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ test1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /mnt/keller_christian/workspace/test1/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ test1 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running de.lathspell.test.UselessThingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.048 s - in de.lathspell.test.UselessThingTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ test1 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple things is that [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) is not bound to any kind of life cycle by default.

This means you have to bind that yourself within your project once.

The documentation says:

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: integration-test.

Which means you have to add to the life cycle at all and then the plugins will bind to `integration-test` life cycle.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

After this you should execute your integration tests simply by using the following:

```
mvn clean verify
```

Update:
If the documentation of a plugins says:

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: x

this means only it is bound to the give life cycle phase if you add an execution as above *but* have not defined `<phase>..</phaseY>`. This is a kind of default which you don't give explicitly in your pom configuration.

Comment: So do I understand correctly:

1. Despite of the above "Bound to phase" output, no plugin is bound to anything except for the defaults from https://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-core/default-bindings.html.

2. Every other plugin has to be manually bound using <execution><goal> 

3. For every manually added <goal> that goal is bound per default to the phase from "Bound to phase".

Comment: The documentation is confusing to me. When I read that it binds by default to X life-cycle phase, I understand that I shouldn't have to add any manual configuration from my part as long the said phase is invoked. What they mean is that it binds by default but not automatically! Fine difference in between there. Thus you have to include the goals in your pom but you don't have to mention the phase, since they bind by default!

Comment: The plugin states that a plugin is bound to a life cycle phase if it's bound to the life cycle in general without explicitly mentioning the life cycle phase..if you define a life cycle phase explicitly via `<phase>...</phase>` it is bound of course to the given phase...